# C++ Compile Time Eigenvalue Evaluation

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I have a question I'm having trouble answering regarding [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/). I would like to compute the eigen values of a matrix **at compile time**. My matrix sizes and values are known in advance. I don't have much experience with Eigen so I'm not sure if this is possible. I know that Eigen doesn't leverage any `constexpr` functions, but it does leverage template meta-programming to construct expression templates.

Is it possible to either:

- wrap some facilities of Eigen in `constexpr` functions to achieve what I want
- use template meta-programming to achieve the same thing

I've poked around google some and haven't found anything which sufficiently answers my question.

I threw together a dumb example which obviously doesn't do what I want it to. The function itself is still called at run-time.

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../eigen/Eigen/Dense"

template<typename T, size_t S>
constexpr Eigen::VectorXcd test()
{
    Eigen::Matrix<T,S,S> a = (Eigen::Matrix<double,S,S>() << 1, 2, 3.4, 5.4).finished();
    auto s = a.eigenvalues();
    return s;
};

int main()
{
    static const Eigen::VectorXcd s {test<double,2>()};
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how feasible this is. At least it is not a top-priority at the moment. There had been a discussion on that here: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/820. If you have any success with making Eigen more `constexpr` aware any information on that would be welcome

Comment: @chtz Thanks for your reply. I see you’re actually a commenter on that thread. I’ll see if I ca poke around but in the mean time I’ll have to find another solution.